# Poetry. Does add install or create a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-poetry

I am getting very confused trying to understand Poetry usage.

I thought you needed `poetry install` to actually install packages (after adding them)
But I have not run that, and only did

```
poetry add pytest --dev
Creating virtualenv rp-poetry-L1ArV34E-py3.9 in /home/myself/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
The --dev option is deprecated, use the `--group dev` notation instead.
Using version ^7.4.4 for pytest

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (0.8s)

Writing lock file

Package operations: 6 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing exceptiongroup (1.2.0)
  • Installing iniconfig (2.0.0)
  • Installing packaging (23.2)
  • Installing pluggy (1.3.0)
  • Installing tomli (2.0.1)
  • Installing pytest (7.4.4)
```

With that I get the following strange things:

- It says that add created a virtual environment! Why???
- I did `ls ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/` and there are **two!** virtual environments (When was the first one created and why `poetry env list` did not report anything)
- I did

  poetry env list

  rp-poetry-L1ArV34E-py3.9 (Activated)

so the virtual environment is activated right!?
Then why when I do this

```
python -c 'import pytest'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
```

but when I do this  `poetry run python -c 'import pytest'` it is OK?

That means that the virtual environment **IS NOT** activated right?

- and last, why is pytest being imported without problem if I have not done `poetry install`

Comment: "_The add command adds required packages to your pyproject.toml and installs them._" according to the [_`poetry add`_ documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#add). And by default, Poetry always installs in virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

- because poetry uses virtual environment as default setting, it creates virtual environments as you actually install any packages in workspace. If poetry detects you are in conda environment which is not `base`, it ignore to create a virtual environment ans uses conda environment.
- There are two possibility, first is `envs.toml` plus your virtual env. `envs.toml` is not a virtual environment. second possibility is you literally created two virtual envs, somehow you may not intended or not.
- no, poetry's virtual environment is not activated in mentioned way. you should run `poetry run python` instead of python. If you want to activate your poetry's environment, you should type `source ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/your_environment`
- it seems for your default python to have pytest.

and, note that all the question you said is on poetry's official docs, https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/.